# Update every row in column to one value in dataframe column in PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am currently trying to convert all rows of a column into one value.

An example dataframe is as such:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | one |
| Second | two |
| Third | three |

Which I would like to convert all values in column B to 'zero' like the following:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| First | zero |
| Second | zero |
| Third | zero |

The approach I am using now relies on using withColumn and utilizing a column expression, but the expression seems rather hacky using df.B == df.B.

```
df = df.withColumn("B", when(df.B == df.B, "zero").otherwise("null"))
```

In pandas this would be more trivial with something equivalent to:

```
df["B"] = "zero"
```

But it doesn't seem pyspark is as simple.

Is there a more succinct way to convert all the values in a column to a single value?

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need the condition.

Answer (score 0):

`df = df.withColumn("B", lit("zero"))`
withColumn(colName, col): Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.